# What does NH and <> mean on a tab?

Tags: guitar, classical-guitar, tablature

On a tab I'm reading, I see this:

```
   NH
   H.
------------------|
------------------|
--<>12------------|
------------------|
------------------|
------------------|
```

What do they mean?
I know H. means a dotted half note and what 12 means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NH and <> both mean the same thing. They're natural harmonics

Comment: Why would anyone use two different signs for the same thing on the same sheet?

Comment: @Tim - Just in case one of them isn't understood, the redundancy might help. Man, I wish I knew what those B-like signs on the stems of notes of sheet music of Roland Dyens's *Libra Sonatine* were when transcribing its last movement, as it's not clear to me what they stand for simply by listening to recordings of that piece....

Comment: @Dekkadeci - so if one wasn't understood, how would that help? One gets played right, the other? Sounds like you need to pose a question...

Comment: @Tim - Since the redundant markings are seen in close proximity of each other, if only one of them is understood, the markings are still respected as a whole.

Comment: @Tim the <> indicates it is a harmonic, but the letters above are telling you what kind of harmonic, it could be A.H (Artificial harmonic), P.H (Pinch harmonic), S.H (semi harmonic), T.H (Tap harmonic).. and sometimes the N.H are written like <12> (with the number inside the signs)